# An Audio Buffer after mpg123_read, what is it? How can I manipulate it?

Tags: c, audio

This is the example code:

```
while (mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK)
        {
                    //  -> I'm consider this line
            if((ao_play(dev, (char*)buffer, done)==0)){
            }
        }
```

In this code i want to edit the audio before it's played. Anyone suggest me to use fft to do this, personally i'm try to do this:

```
while (mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK)
        {
            buffer=((int)buffer)*2
            if((ao_play(dev, (char*)buffer, done)==0))
        }
```

for experiment, but this can't do anything. So, what is a buffer? How i can change it in real time? And can i stop it and after resume it (also called "pause" in music player..)?
Sorry for noob questions but I'm starting to program just from 6 months.

Comment: your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928794/how-can-i-edit-this-audio-buffer

Comment: I deleted it because it's mistaken

Comment: but this one is no better....

Answer (score 1):

A buffer is a memory block used to contain an arbitrary, up bounded amount of data. In C, it's used as an array. If the buffer is dynamically allocated, then the variable `buffer` is a pointer that points to the address where the actual buffer (memory block) begins. You have to look at the declaration of variable `buffer` to know what is the type of the elements inside such array.

Also you have to look at the mpg123 documentation to know how to interpret the data that is returned by the `mpg123_read()` function.

Making an educated guess based upon the nature of the data you have decoded, I would say that `buffer` is probably an array of interleaved short ints that comprises data for stereo channels L and R of an uncompressed 16-bit audio signal. Channel L being at even indexed elements, and channel R being at odd indexed elements.

So, a possible editing would be like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<done;i+=2)
{
  buffer[i] = (buffer[i+1] - buffer[i]) / 2;
}
```

This would substract left channel data with right channel data, cancelling any audio data that is identical on both channels. It's the basic technique for cancelling vocals in a song.

Your proposed editing has no meaning. You are changing the value of the pointer `buffer` by multiplying it by two. That makes the pointer to have a very different memory address, much possibly illegal, so when that pointer is used in `ao_play()` you will get a segmentation fault.

I guess that what you want to do with your example is to make your audio data twice louder, don't you? In that case, you are looking for this:

```
for (int i=0;i<done;i+=2)
{
  if (buffer[i]>16383)
     buffer[i] = 32767;
  else if (buffer[i]<-16384)
     buffer[i] = -32768;
  else
     buffer[i] = 2*buffer[i];
}
```

To stop and resume, you have to find a way for your program to check the value of something you can change with an input device (a button pressed in a window, a key pressed, etc).

For example, let's say you have a function called `khbit()` that returns non zero if a key is being pressed (this function is present in DOS compilers and sometimes is available as non-standard library for easing portability of older DOS programs: look at `conio.h` if you have it). Then you can do something like this:

```
int paused = 0;  /* flip-flop variable to pause/resume playing */
while (mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK)
{
  if (!paused)
  {
    if((ao_play(dev, (char*)buffer, done)==0))
       break;
  }
  if (kbhit() && getchar()==' ')
     paused = !paused;
}
```

This will play/pause your music using the SPACE bar.

Answer (score 0):

It will not pause the music, only mute it. Reading (`mpg123_read`) goes on so you're just skipping a part.